# Integrating Bulma/Sass With Django

Tags: css, django, sass, bulma

I have a Django project that I would like to integrate with Bulma/Sass using the [django-sass-processor](https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor) framework. Upon initial file creation I am able to compile `.scss` to `.css`, but when I try: `sass website.scss --watch` I get `ERROR: --watch is not allowed when printing to stdout.`

I also tried: `sass --watch website.scss:/static/website/css/website.css` and I get `Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop. Error reading ../../../../../../static: Creation failed.`

Is the issue in creating the new `.css` file due to permissions?

```
root
  -> website
       -> static
           -> css
               - website.css
  - urls.py
  - views.py
  - website.scss `
```

**settings.py**

```
 STATIC_ROOT = '/static'
 SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = 'website/static'`
```

Answer (score 0):

After recreating my initial `.scss` and `.css` files with: `sass --watch website.scss:/static/website/css/website.css`, Sass was able to create directories/files and compile files as needed.